# how to change text color on focus a cell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, ios-4.2

I am working on a app and i have a main table view. By default in iPhone if a cell is on focus its font color changes to white. I used this code to set the font of my cell:

```
lblTemp.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
lblTemp.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

When a cell is on focus its text color doesn't change to white. it remains black. how can i change a text's color oc a cell to white when its on focus. Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `highlightedTextColor` property to your label:

```
lblTemp.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```